# Is it possible to upload large files to Ktor & Netty server?

Tags: kotlin, netty, ktor

I was making a simple file upload&download service and found out that, as far as I understand, Netty doesn't release direct buffers until request processing is over. As a result, I can't upload bigger files.

I was trying to make sure that the problem is not inside my code, so I created the most simple tiny Ktor application:

```kotlin
routing {
    post("upload") {
        call.receiveMultipart().forEachPart {}
        call.respond(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    }
}
```

The default direct memory size is about 3Gb, to make test simpler I limit it with:

```kotlin
System.setProperty("io.netty.maxDirectMemory", (10 * 1024 * 1024).toString())
```

before starting the NettyApplicationEngine.

Now if I upload a large file, for example with httpie, I got "Connection reset":

```
http -v --form POST http://localhost:42195/upload file@/tmp/FileStorageLoadTest-test-data1.tmp

http: error: ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')) while doing POST request to URL: http://localhost:42195/upload
```

On the server side there is no information about the problem except for the "java.io.IOException: Broken delimiter occurred" exception. But if I put the breakpoint in NettyResponsePipeline#processCallFailed, the real exception is:

```
io.netty.util.internal.OutOfDirectMemoryError: failed to allocate 65536 byte(s) of direct memory (used: 10420231, max: 10485760)
```

It is a pity that this exception is not logged.

Also, I found out that the same code works without problems if I use Jetty engine instead.

Environment:

```
Ubuntu Linux
Java 8
Ktor=1.2.5
netty-transport-native-epoll=4.1.43.Final
```

(but if Netty started without native-epoll support, the problem is the same)

Comment: Did you find the solution ?

Comment: @SaurabhPadwekar, switching from Netty to Jetty was enough for me in that case.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So, after changing Netty to Jetty, Whether this code `call.receiveMultipart().forEachPart {}` was able to release buffer? I know I am asking too much, but will it be possible for you to share the code snippet to show how you manage to receive multipart chunks of bigger files without causing the memory to leak. Thank you.

Comment: @SaurabhPadwekar, implementation in Jetty is quite different, there is no problem with direct memory. It is 25% slower though.
Also I have to use Apache FileUpload instead of ktor default CIOMultipartDataBase, because CIOMultipartDataBase saves temporary file to disk during upload which is inappropriate for my service.

The upload code starts with FileUpload().getItemIterator(KtorUploadRequestContext(call.request)), where FileUpload is from Apache and KtorUploadRequestContext is my very simple implementation of org.apache.commons.fileupload.UploadContext.

Comment: @NikitaTukkel after 2.5 years later Netty still cant upload large file ((